# Using multiple local folders as source in hadoop mapreduce job

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I have data in multiple local folders i.e. /usr/bigboss/data1, /usr/bigboss/data2 and many more folders. I want to use all of these folders as input source for my MapReduce command and store the result at HDFS. I can not find a working command to use Hadoop Grep example to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data will need to reside in HDFS for you to process it with the grep example. You can upload the folders to HDFS using the -put FsShell command:

```
hadoop fs -mkdir bigboss
hadoop fs -put /usr/bigboss/data* bigboss
```

Which will create a folder in the current user HDFS directory, and upload each of the data directories to it

Now you should be able to run the grep example over the data